# Cordova Android & iOS compatibility?

Tags: cordova

Can someone tell me what are the minimum and maximum guarantees versions of Android and of iOS supported by the latest release of Cordova Cli please? 
Or where I could found this informations quickly please?

I'm starting to go round in circles on this question... :(

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: PS: I've already googled about it for few hours and can't find any explicite informations about it :(

Comment: Check it here: http://cordova.apache.org/

Comment: @AAhad Thanks AAhad, I had already have a look on their website ;)
But I did not find there any explicit information about that :(
I'm looking for something like: "Android: from 4.1 to 5.0 | iOS: from 6.0 to 8.1" .

Comment: ios, right now, 6.0 and greater, android I think it's 2.3 and greater. iOS 6.0 support can be dropped soon.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for!
I'm confused, but could you tell me where you've found this informations please?

Comment: I just know. iOS 5 support was dropped on cordova 3.5 http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/05/23/cordova-350.html. So, until new announcement, iOS 6 is supported. I haven't read anything about dropping android 2.3 support, so it should be supported, but not sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest supported versions are:

**Apache Cordova iOS 3.7.0**

**Details**: http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/11/06/cordova-ios-3.7.0.html

**Release Date**: 06 Nov 2014

Read this as well: 
**Cordova iOS and iOS 8:** http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/cordova-ios-and-ios-8/

**Cordova Android API docs:**

**Cordova supports Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread, starting with Android API level 10) and 4.x.**
([read more](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html))

Some interesting info that might help you as well.

Apple has recently announced that new and updated apps submitted to the Apple App Store must include **64-bit** support for them to be approved. This change will be implemented by the Apple App Store starting **February 1, 2015.**

This means that starting at that time, Cordova-based apps **should** be built using a version of Cordova that has **64-bit iOS support**.

The first version of Cordova to include 64-bit for iOS is 3.4.1. Therefore, to meet these requirements of the Apple App Store, you should be using **at least** version **3.4.1** of Cordova before this **February deadline**. ([read](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/11/25/ios-64bit.html))

Comment: Hi @AAhad , that are really interesting informations for me (and it will be considered and used!). But I had already read your links and cannot provide a complete answer as expected to my partners from only that :(
Thanks anyway ;)